# How to return data from 2 tables with foreign keys in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to return a view with 2 tables, `orders` and `order_menu`. What I want to do is to display what orders the customer ordered based on order_id to my view.

Here is the database table for [orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6w9o.png) and this is database table for [order_menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4dJ8.png).

I've tried using join table in my controller but it won't work. Here is my controller:

```
 public function show(Order $order)
 {
    $data = DB::table('order_menu')
        ->join('menus', 'menus.id', '=', 'order_menu.menu_id')
        ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_menu.order_id')
        ->select('orders.*', 'menus.name', 'order_menu.quantity')
        ->get();

    return view('admin.order.detail')->with([
        'order' => $order,
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

Is there any solutions to solve this?

Comment: Can you define *but it won't work* what is not working ? what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid it fetches all of the data in ```order_menu```, while I only need the data that is connected to the id in ```order``` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a filter for order id in your query, I assume `$order` is the instance of model and has order data

```
$data = DB::table('order_menu')
    ->join('menus', 'menus.id', '=', 'order_menu.menu_id')
    ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_menu.order_id')
    ->select('orders.*', 'menus.name', 'order_menu.quantity')
    ->where('orders.id', $order->id)
    ->get();
```

Or if you already have relations in place in your model then using eloquent you can query the data as

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function menus()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Menu::class, 'order_menu ', 'order_id', 'menu_id')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
class Menu extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_menu ', 'menu_id','order_id');
    }
}

$data = Order::with('menus')->find($order->id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function show(Order $order)
{
    $data = DB::table('orders*')
        ->join('order_menu*', 'order_menu.id', '=', 'orders.id')
        ->groupBy('orders.id')
        ->get();

    return view('admin.order.detail')->with([
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an error saying "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mieaceh.orders*' doesn't exist"